# Understanding openssl. Where is the cert file?

Tags: openssl

I am using the command ...

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect reds-cluster-01:443
```

And I get the output:

```
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = RapidSSL TLS DV RSA Mixed SHA256 2020 CA-1
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.my-co-example.com
verify return:1
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=*.my-co-example.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=RapidSSL TLS DV RSA Mixed SHA256 2020 CA-1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBZ
...
```

I assume that means somewhere on the filesystem of my server there would be a file somewhere that has the string ...

```
MIIGnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBZ
```

... in it.  How can I find that file without having to execute something like?

```
sudo grep -sr MIIGnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBZ /
```

Comment: If you're wondering where your server keeps it certificate, read the *config files* and documentation for the server! Certificates may be stored in binary form as well.

Comment: There are a lot of config files.  Which ones?

Comment: If you don't know which service listens on port 443, that's your problem - not certificates.

Comment: @vidarlo `lsof -i :443` on my server tells me that `nginx` is listening on port 443.   And looking at nginx conf tells me where the file is! Thanks